# Comment traduire « has not risen to the mantle of the office » : « n'a pas endossé le costume de sa fonction » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

> [...] But, on balance, his conduct over the past two years,
>   particularly his actions last month, is evidence that the president
>   **has not [risen](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rise&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) to the [mantle](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mantle&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) of the [office](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=office&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)**.
>
> [ « Mitt Romney: The president shapes the public character of the
>   nation. Trump’s character falls short. » Le sénateur Mitt Romney, ds.
>   le [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/mitt-romney-the-president-shapes-the-public-character-of-the-nation-trumps-character-falls-short/2019/01/01/37a3c8c2-0d1a-11e9-8938-5898adc28fa2_story.html) ]
>
> ---
>
> « [...] Sa conduite ces deux dernières années et tout particulièrement ses
>   mesures ce mois-ci démontrent que le président **n'a pas endossé le
>   costume de sa fonction** » [...]
>
> [ « Trump n'a «pas endossé le costume» de président, dit Romney » ds.
>   [La Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/02/01-5209719-trump-na-pas-endosse-le-costume-de-president-dit-romney.php) via l'AFP ]

Dans la partie de l'extrait soulignée, on a le verbe [*to rise*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/rise/608028?q=risen) (selon des contextes similaires : *monter, réussir, devenir, faire son chemin* etc.) avec un nom ([*mantle*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/mantle/593971)) (un « manteau », employé au figuré) et un complément du nom (*of the* [*office*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/office/598650)). On semble s'appuyer dans la traduction sur une locution comme *[endosser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/endosser) l'uniforme*, mettre sur son dos (TLFi)...

- *Endosser le costume d'une fonction*, est-ce une formulation idiomatique et usuelle en français ?
- Pourquoi est-ce une traduction adéquate (ou non)... est-elle plus ou
  moins adéquate selon qu'on l'associe à l'école de pensée
  [*sourcière*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traduction#%C3%89coles_de_pens%C3%A9e) ou *cibliste* en traduction ?
- Autrement que suggère-t-on comme traduction ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression (*Le costume d'une fonction*). Une expression pouvant être similaire serait **n'a pas la tête de l'emploi** https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_la_t%C3%AAte_de_l%E2%80%99emploi

Comment: @AdriDev Merci ! Je connais l'expression à laquelle vous faites référence. Je vous invite à développer le tout en réponse afin de valider si votre proposition trouve des appuis. Il faudra un verbe pour émuler _to rise_ et donc le verbe de l'expression sera à l'infinitif... serait-ce usuel, le sens du verbe précédant l'expression viendra-t-il supplanter le sens de celle-ci ?

Comment: je ne pense pas pourquoi beaucoup développer sur cette expression car j'ai de très faible connaissance sur ces sujets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans *Le Petit Robert* (2010), je trouve à ***endosser*** :

> LOCUTION VIEILLIE *Endosser la soutane* [devenir prêtre, mentionné à l’article **soutane**]. *Endosser l’uniforme* : entrer dans l’armée.

Il semble donc que l’expression voulant que l’on endosse un habit corresponde bien à l’idée d’occuper un poste, de prendre une position ou d’acquérir un statut. L’habit endossé est parfois si marqué que la simple mention de son nom suffit à comprendre :

- la **soutane** et l’**uniforme** de la définition citée
- *« Annoncer qu’untel va [**endosser l’habit vert**](https://lestribulationsdunfrancophoneenfrancophonie.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/pas-de-sepulture-pour-les-hommes-verts/) revient à dire qu’il va devenir académicien. »*

Pour l’exemple de la question, il semble que l’on a préféré appeler l’habit présidentiel *« le costume de [l]a fonction »*, tout simplement.

On pourra aussi mentionner *« [endosser](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/endosser) le **harnais** »*, c’est-à-dire se mettre à travailler.

Je ne suis pas certain à quel point ce style d’expression est suranné. Il ne me surprend pas et me semble parfaitement régulier, courant, habituel. Je la rapprocherais un peu de l’expression que j’emploie à un niveau familial (et dont l’[absence sur internet](https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&ei=NEIuXKybJo-Z_QaOo4KIDg&q=%22sauter+dans+les+bottines%22&oq=%22sauter+dans+les+bottines%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17952.17952..18230...0.0..0.76.76.1......0....1..gws-wiz.4xcA_iu-b3U) me prend par surprise ici et maintenant) *« sauter dans les bottines de qqn »* : prendre sa place, assumer ses fonctions, etc.

Par ailleurs, elle est assez habituelle pour être facile à trouver à plusieurs sauces sur Google News :

- **Endosser l’habit de réalisateur** lui a bien plu.
      <sub>— [Source](https://www.telerama.fr/cinema/swann-arlaud-a-laffiche-dun-beau-voyou-un-amoureux-de-poesie-et-dabsurde,n6074806.php)</sub>
- Il faut dire qu'il est facile d’**endosser l'habit de capitaine** du *Nieuwe Sorgh*. Car ce navire est proposé à la location.
      <sub>— [Source](https://www.letelegramme.fr/soir/tourisme-a-l-abordage-d-une-nuit-sur-la-rance-18-05-2018-11963008.php)</sub>
- Victoria Bedos a hâte d’**endosser l'habit de jurée**
      <sub>— [Source](https://www.ouest-france.fr/bretagne/dinard-35800/victoria-bedos-hate-d-endosser-l-habit-de-juree-4525653)</sub>

Vieillie donc ? Le TLFi ne l’indique pas ainsi, et j’aurais tendance à me ranger de ce côté.

---

Quant au **mantle** de l’anglais, on pensera bien sûr à un habit. Mais était-ce vraiment une image sur l’habit ?

Selon [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mantle) :

> a position of authority or responsibility

Selon [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mantle) :

> An important role or responsibility that passes from one person to another.

Selon [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mantle) :

> a figurative cloak symbolizing preeminence or authority.

À la lumière de ces trois entrées, je vois que selon la dernière, il y aurait filiation au moins, mais selon les deux autres, je perçois aussi que l’image semble s’être quelque peu émancipée de ses origines. Va pour l’habit, néanmoins.

---

#### En conclusion

Autant ciblistes que sourciers pourraient s’entendre que l’expression proposée est au moins dans une certaine mesure acceptable. Si elle est possiblement rare ou vieillie, elle est néanmoins encore présente dans la langue, et encore assez présente pour ne pas inspirer au lectorat un parfum médiéval.

Une traduction sourcière chercherait probablement à incorporer d’une manière ou d’une autre *« to rise »*, très possiblement en parlant de se hisser à un certain niveau jugé acceptable, ainsi que proposé en commentaire ci-dessous par l’OP en personne. *Une certaine représentation de la chose pourrait être l’idée de bien remplir les épaules du vêtements, mais je le mentionne en badinant seulement, car cette image ne correspond à rien de commun ou même rare la langue habituelle.*

Une traduction cibliste se contentera sans doute plus facilement de l’image d’insuffisance à la tâche, en ce sens que le président qui n’a pas endossé son costume de fonction ne semble pas avoir cru bon ou été capable d’agir ainsi que l’on s’attend (à tort ou à raison) de la part d’un président.

Mais on remarquera aussi que dans le cas de l’actualité, les traductions seront le plus souvent ciblistes, ce qui semble logique : on ne traduit pas là une œuvre d’art, et on ne saurait s’attendre du lectorat qu’il se familiarise quotidiennenement avec des tours de langues et des images tirés de l’hébreux, de l’arabe, du chinois, de l’allemend, du swahili, de l’espagnol, du gaélique et j’en passe sous prétexte que ce sont des gens de toutes ces cultures linguistiques qui écrivent des nouvelles qui pour eux sont locales, mais dont la portée dépasse parfois les frontières de leurs pays, les rendant intéressantes ou pertinentes pour des gens d’ailleurs.

S’il y avait quoi que ce soit à en redire, je proposerais peut-être (avec le risque de suranalyser l’original anglais) :

- [...] n’a pas su endosser [...]

Comment: Merci ! Le verbe _savoir_ fait plus que simplement assurer une meilleure formulation dans votre proposition, je le comprends comme « n'a pas été capable ». Je préfère personnellement l'idée de hauteur, de niveau ou de barre à celle d'endosser à l'état pur. Je note que les exemples sur News semble avoir un caractère transitoire ou éphémère par opposition à la _vocation_. Bien intéressant, merci !

Comment: Il me semble que président des États-Unis est aussi une fonction transitoire pour un individu donné. Endosser la soutane, par contre, souligne la prise d'un état, permanent cette fois. Ainsi que l’habit vert, à quelques très rares exceptions près. Je ne suis pas certain de savoir de quelle manière analyser tout ça (les exemples éphémères vs ceux plus durables ou permanents).

Comment: Merci ! Bien vu, parfois ce que je peux observer n'est que partiel ou n'est pas significatif...

Comment: Quant au verbe *savoir*, je percevais l'expression d'une incapacité du président dans l'original anglais, mais je peux aussi me tromper. En quoi votre vision diffère-t-elle?

Comment: J'imagine que d'une certaine manière je pense à _hisser_, au même niveau que la _star spangled banner_ (_O'er the land of the free_) ou à l'idée d'étoffe. Ma réflexion progresse, merci !

Answer (score 3):

J'ai entendu cette traduction littérale à la radio (France Inter) ce matin. Elle n'est pas habituelle mais se comprend bien. On pourrait considérer qu'elle est le pendant de l'expression plus commune "l'habit fait le moine". J'aurais plutôt choisi "il n'a pas pris la mesure de la fonction". J'ignore l'origine de cette dernière expression, assez commune,  on peut la relier au choix d'un costume assez grand, mais je m'avance trop peut-être

Comment: Merci ! Pouvez-vou svp. préciser davantage ce que veut dire exactement _ne pas prendre la mesure d'une fonction_ ? Est-ce _comprendre l'étendue_ ou ne pas faire le poids, ne pas être de taille ?

Comment: Je l'interprète ainsi : il n'a pas compris ce qu'il devait faire, comment le faire, ni les conséquences de ses actes. Il s'agit d'une sentence sans appel, qui implique qu'il n'a pas été à la hauteur effectivement

Comment: *«L’habit **ne** fait **pas** le moine»* me semble tout de même plus commun que l’antithèse citée ici, que je perçois davantage comme une parodie de la première.

Comment: @Montéedelait Vous avez sûrement raison. Je lis et regarde trop de parodies ... Je perds parfois le fil

Answer (score 1):

> Endosser le costume d'une fonction, est-ce une formulation idiomatique
>   et usuelle en français ?

Non, en tant que Français je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression.

> Pourquoi est-ce une traduction adéquate (ou non)... est-elle plus ou
>   moins adéquate selon qu'on l'associe à l'école de pensée sourcière ou
>   cibliste en traduction ?

Sourcier comme cibliste, étant donné que l'expression n'a pas de sens en français, il s'agit d'une mauvaise traduction de mon point de vue.

---

> Autrement que suggère-t-on comme traduction ?

Pour rester proche du vocabulaire utilisé et ne pas changer le reste de la phrase , je changerais surtout la traduction de "*not risen*" par "*n'a pas été à la hauteur*" :

> Sa conduite ces deux dernières années et tout particulièrement ses mesures ce mois-ci démontrent que le président ***n'a pas été à la hauteur du* costume de sa fonction**

Mais si je devais traduire ce passage, je changerais un peu plus la phrase de façon à ce que l'expression soit plus compréhensible et paraisse plus naturelle :

> Sa conduite ces deux dernières années et tout particulièrement ses mesures ce mois-ci démontrent **qu'il n'a pas été à la hauteur du costume de président**

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement, cette métaphore n'existe pas en français.

Le plus proche, à mon sens et pour le moment, serait:

> il n'a pas été à la hauteur de ses responsabilités de président.